# The alternate style for ListBox in WPF not working as expected if the collection has some items which needs to be hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to bind my collection to a listbox. **The collection contains some items which are to be hidden and are to be shown based on certain conditions**.But when I do this the alternate styles are not applied properly.

For example:
Case 1 : where all items are visible, I get the output like this:
Item1(grey)
Item2(white)
Item3(grey)
Item4(white)
Item5(grey)
Item6(white)
Item7(grey)

Case2: where Item2 is hidden, I get the output as:
Item1(grey)
Item3(grey)
Item4(white)
Item5(grey)
Item6(white)
Item7(grey)

How do I resolve this **without rebinding the collection**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than hide the items (presumably in the `ListBoxItem` control template, or the `ListBox` `ItemTemplate`), you should use a `CollectionViewSource` to filter them out.

This is because the items are still technically there - you cannot see them but the listbox can.

See this link for details on filtering.
http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

> To filter a collection view you can define a callback method that
>   determines if the item should be part of the view or not. That method
>   should have the following signature: bool Filter(object item). Now set
>   the delegate of that method to the Filter property of the
>   CollectionView and you're done.

```
ICollectionView _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
_customerView.Filter = CustomerFilter

private bool CustomerFilter(object item)
{
    Customer customer = item as Customer;
    return customer.Name.Contains( _filterString );
}
```

Comment: Actually this didn't resolve my problem. Suppose Item1 is my checkbox, and on Item1=true, I want the Item2 to be visible. If I go with the above approach I need to rebind my collection to the control, which I want to prevent.

Comment: @RaviDugar This didn't solve your problem or you didnt try it because its a bit more work than anticipated? At some point, the collection you are binding to will need to change, either by binding the ItemsControl to a Collectionviewsource or by removing elements from the source collection. I suggested collectionviewsource because we are solving display problem.

Comment: I did try the above solution and it indeed resolved the display problem. I want my collection(fixed number of items) not to change as I have 1000's of records in it. If my collection changes it would give a flickering affect in the window.Can you please suggest any other way ?